# Star Wars Varactyl's voice

Tags: creature-vocalizations, iconic-sounds

I've reviewed modern “Star Wars” trilogy and one sound just blew my mind.
It was Varactyl's voice in the third episode. The hooting call at the very beginning:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPPKEW02CXk

I've tried to find the information about the creation of this sound but I only found this article:
http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Varactyl

Maybe somebody knows anything about the history of this sound. How was it made? Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean the Boga roar? That's what I see on that clip. Anyway, I have the Star Wars book and it says a combination of dolphin, Tasmanian Devil, dog and coyote were used for that creature. Can definitely hear the dolphin at the start of that clip ;)

Answer (score 1):

When i was a child i had a guinea pig. Every time i opened the fridge he would make this exact sound, only pitched up. 
Not saying that this is how its done, but i believe it could be done by recording a guinea pig at a high khz, and pitch it down to taste.

Best wishes

Mikkel

Comment: Great idea Mikkel! They definitely have the same pitch change character. I think this is the main point here. Later it might be anything what sound designer wants.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is in the Sound of Star Wars book? I read parts of the book but it covers so much, I can't remember.

Answer (score 1):

Ben Burtt uses a program called Kyma for a lot of his sound design work.  It is definitely a combination of the animals Andy mentioned processed and combined in Kyma.

Answer (score 1):

Lol bogs is the name for that certain varactyl and it is also used as a voice of the pokemon Palkia, Read http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Varactyl under the "behind the scenes" tab